# unable to start rails server in cloud9 using terminal command "rails s -b $IP -p $port"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm unable to start rails server in cloud9.
I run command

`rails s -b $IP -p $port`

and it gives the following output

```
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': invalid argument: -p -b (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:316:in `parse_options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:191:in `options'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in `set_environment'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer for this from another forum and it worked. I have just changed "$port" to "$PORT". I am not sure if it is because of case sensitivity.

Comment: Environment variables should always be set and called with full caps. And yes Linux unlike Windows is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, Johan. That could be the reason for the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It will be `server` or `s` not `-s` like below

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

or

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Comment: I have tried the same by removing "-" as the prefix for "s" but it did not work.